# Supabase magic link authentication in Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, authentication, supabase, supabase-js

I am doing magic link authentication in Vanilla JS and when I click on the magic link received on the email it redirects to this URL http://192.168.100.42:5500/#access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJhdXRoZW50aWNhdGVkIiwiZXhwIjoxNjg4MzMxNzgxLCJzdWIiOiJlMTNlZDVlNC00OWI5LTQ5ZDgtOWNjNS01YWNjYWYzNTc0NDQiLCJlbWFpbCI6ImludGVsbGlnZW50amF3YWRAZ21haWwuY29tIiwicGhvbmUiOiIiLCJhcHBfbWV0YWRhdGEiOnsicHJvdmlkZXIiOiJlbWFpbCIsInByb3ZpZGVycyI6WyJlbWFpbCJdfSwidXNlcl9tZXRhZGF0YSI6e30sInJvbGUiOiJhdXRoZW50aWNhdGVkIiwiYWFsIjoiYWFsMSIsImFtciI6W3sibWV0aG9kIjoib3RwIiwidGltZXN0YW1wIjoxNjg4MzI4MTgxfV0sInNlc3Npb25faWQiOiJlMDg5OGJjZS03NjE3LTQ5MWQtODdiMy1kYThiMDYwMTliOWEifQ.JvxQlLdCckhNgq4dq9Sqf4yz7sGXRY0sL8Ipjs3KuIw&expires_in=3600&refresh_token=ky9vgfwhZz7GEA3mQRV1NA&token_type=bearer&type=magiclink

The redirect URL should be just "http://192.168.100.42:5500" and also there is no user data in local storage or in session.

```
// *magic link login with supabase*
const magicLinkForm = document.getElementById("magic-link-form");
const sendLink = document.getElementById("sendLink");
const userPrompt = document.getElementById("userPrompt");
const cardData = document.getElementById("cardData");
const _supabase = supabase.createClient(
  "https://vorgmkkmxuwpruztecpu.supabase.co",
  "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJzdXBhYmFzZSIsInJlZiI6InZvcmdta2tteHV3cHJ1enRlY3B1Iiwicm9sZSI6ImFub24iLCJpYXQiOjE2ODgzMTkzNDQsImV4cCI6MjAwMzg5NTM0NH0.HY_fteEtLcTOZjtD17VkuVfEjjfzBbLcP1Q2784y7cU"
);
userPrompt.style.display = "none";
magicLinkForm.addEventListener("submit", async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  const { data, error } = await _supabase.auth.signInWithOtp({
    email,
    options: {
      emailRedirectTo: "http://192.168.100.42:5500",
    },
  });
  cardData.style.display = "none";
  userPrompt.style.display = "block";
  console.log("data", data);
});
```

I am trying to send the magic link on the given email and when user click that link, he/she should be signed in and redirected on the given url and also want to make some routes only accessible after logged in.

Comment: You are getting the correct redirect URL. The access token and the refresh token are added at the end of the redirect URL, and that is how the user is signed in using magic link.

Comment: @dshukertjr Yes, that is correct. But what I see usually after redirecting the URL changes back to like "https://localhost:3000/home" within a few seconds but in my case it does remain with all the access token and other params.

Comment: On your `http://192.168.100.42:5500` page, are you also initializing Supabase?

Comment: @dshukertjr I did miss that part. Thank you so much it is working now!